# Convert a Google Sign-in idToken to a Firebase IdToken using only HTTP

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I am trying to use the Firestore HTTP REST APIs from React Native.

I am only using HTTP (no SDK).

After the user has logged in with Google Signin (react-native-google-signin), I have an `idToken` and  `accessToken`.

I want to be able to convert one of these into a Firebase `idToken` that can be used in the `'Authorization': 'Bearer ${firebaseIdToken}'` HTTP header **using only the Firebase REST HTTP APIs**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-verify-custom-token

- Input "token"="A Firebase Auth custom token".

  - Neither `idToken` or `accessToken` from the Google Signin work here.
  - Do I need to send the Google `idToken` to the server to convert it to a Firebase Auth `idToken`?

Before I was using these SDK calls for auth:

```
const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken, accessToken);
await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred)
const firebaseIdToken = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();
const headers = { 
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${firebaseIdToken}`
}
```

**Related links**

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the REST API to exchange an OAuth credential for a Firebase ID token:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential